# Quartz 2D or OpenGL ES? Pros and cons in the long term, possibility of migration to other platforms

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, opengl-es, quartz-2d

I'm having a hard time deciding whether to go with Quartz2D or OpenGL for an iPad game. It will be 2D mostly, but effect-intense (simultaneous lighting effects for 10-30 objects, 10-20 simultaneous animations on the screen).
So far, assuming i'm equally dumb in both technologies and have to learn them from the ground, i came to this list. (I've read several topics here, on SO, with names like "Quartz or OpenGL", but i'm still left with some questions)

**Quartz**:

- Better time-to-market, because of
  ready to use absractions like UIView,
  UIImageView, CoreAnimation
  abstractions

**Open GL ES**

- Closer to hardware, thus, performance
  is better.
- App, implemented with OpenGL ES can be easier migrated to Android, MeeGo, Windows Phone, etc.

My questions are:

1. How time will it take to rewrite
   Quartz 2d app to use OpenGL? Lets
   say it took me 2 man-month to write
   Quartz app, how much time will i
   need to rewrite it? (Please, just some subjective opinions, i'll try to summarize them somehow)
2. Regarding the ease of migration to other platforms, when using OpenGL, is it really so?
   Or efforts when migrating Quartz app from iPhoneOS to Android will be not so much bigger, compared to OpenGL app migration? (Ease of migration is quite important criterion)
3. Regarding OpenGL, should i go with OpenGL 1.1 or 2.0, concerning migration? (Android supports 2.0 through NDK, but dont know whether NDK's use will increase or decrease migration efforts)

Answer (score 3):

use a framework that is cross platform

Cocos2d for android:
http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/

Cocos2d for iphone:

http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/

Comment: Do you know, what version of OpenGL ES Cocos2d for android uses?

Answer (score 1):

I will only answer `Android` related part of your question since I don't have any knowledge regarding `Quartz`

The biggest difference between `OpenGL ES 1.1` and `2.0` is the programmable pipeline In `1.1` there is a default fixed pipeline, but in `2.0` the pipeline changed to programmable so you have to write youw own pipeline even to do some lighting. And there is a lot of time since your question, now `Android` supports `OpenGL ES 2.0` with its framework API also alongside with `NDK`. For the usage rates according to `Android` dashboard; 99.8 % of `Android` devices support both `version 2.0` & `1.1` 
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL

P.S `OpenGL ES 3.0` is introduced with `Android 4.3` so these rates might be subject to change.

For Cocos2D related question in above answer, `Cocos2D-X` uses `OpenGL ES 2.0` in `Android` so it is also high probable that `Cocos2D for Android` uses `OpenGL ES 2.0`, too.