# should i learn Quartz for iphone game programming?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, quartz-2d

I wanna learn and develop 2d game on iphone but i don't know if i should learn Quartz 2d first, or i can just jump into openGL ES directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quartz 2D or OpenGL ES? Pros and cons in the long term, possibility of migration to other platforms.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598408/quartz-2d-or-opengl-es-pros-and-cons-in-the-long-term-possibility-of-migration)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to take a look at [cosos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) first...

Answer (score 0):

*This should be a comment but i'm not allowed to comment yet:*

Your question is subjective. The answer depends on what kind of game you want.
You can always use UIKit and CoreAnimation (Quartz) for simple 2d animations/games. If you want to build heavy/complex/3D animations with good frame rates you might try OpenGL but it will be harder to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning OpenGLES now, and it's not simple. That said, there's probably more documentation out there for it, and Apple has a lot of stuff held in its dev center.

Look at it this way - learning OpenGLES now will pay off in the future, as OGL works on just about every platform under the sun, or hidden away from the sun indoors. If I were you, I'd bite the bullet and learn OES.

Answer (score 0):

[Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) is a great tool kit for developing 2D games and applications quickly and easily.